# I want to have my image augmented every time using keras.preprocessing layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-preprocessing

I was doing some augmentations for my DL project.
I want to augment (flip) my image every time but the preprocessing layer do it randomly for some of the images and leaves some as it is.

```
tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode=HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL, seed=None, **kwargs)
```

I think it has something to do with the seed value but I don't know which value to set.

Thanks

Comment: Just try any seed value. It just does not matter what you choose.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed. By the way, you use RandomFlip. Just pay attention "Random" & "Flip". You will always get random flip with pseudorandom or not. If you want some specific, then look into other layers

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?